# How to create an error on dereferencing a nullpointer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc

The following code compiles without error and runs without segmentation fault:

```
int* a = 0;
int& b = *a;
```

We do have a nullpointer in the reference. This reference may be moved in the project for a while until it gets used. When it gets used it will produce a segmentation fault.

The currently used compilers are MSVC 10.0 and gcc 4.9.
To ease the finding of the error I want the dereferencing to fail on nullpointers so that the segmentation fault is caused in the above code. Is it possible to achieve this and how?

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), and sometimes UB might actually *seem* to work. It might also be possible that the compiler have optimized out the code. As long as you have UB it's not really possible to say anything else, or to predict something.

Comment: When running in debug mode, your favorit ide will give the location of the error.

Comment: Consider using std::optional instead of a pointer and a reference.

Comment: I'd say you shouldn't worry about this. In most real cases you'd get a segfault.

Comment: For debugging purposes tools like debuggers (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) help a lot. But they don't make your program "fail" on null dereference; it is still undefined behavior (and often but not always your program still crashes). Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Comment: You might have some luck with static code analyzer tools.

Comment: Don't think that answers here are that helpful, the behavior is undefined but it doesn't preclude a compiler from generating nullptr assertion check in debug mode for each dereference/ member access on pointer. However I don't think that even modern versions of compilers provide such an option. One possibility is to make your own class for raw ptrs and put assertions to relevant operators (also could be used for forbidding pointer arithmetic etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gcc, you have the address sanitizer which is a flag make the compiler add some code that cause crashes when you try to access invalid addresses (out of bound, null pointer, ...).

You can search `-fsanitize=address` in [gcc's documentation for instrumentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html).

When using a sanitizer (with gcc) you have to link to the sanitizer.
For example:

```
g++ -fsanitize=address -c -o file.o file.cpp
g++ -o a.out file.o -fsanitize=address
```

I don't think that MSVC has a similar mechanism.

Comment: I tried a small example, it does not move the error into another place but gives an enhanced error message. The docu at [link](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAlgorithm) stated that the operator has been replaced. I expected the error to occur at the dereferenciation itself.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

You might not *necessarily* get a segmentation fault (the compiler might even optimise out the offending statements), so don't rely on this technique in portable C++.

If you want to crash your program then use `std::abort();`, or `std::terminate();`

If you want to test a pointer `ptr` for nullness then use

```
if (!ptr){
    // ptr is nullptr
}
```

References:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort
 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate

Comment: I am under the impression that the OP is searching for a compiler flag or an analysis tool that will catch these kind of bugs.

Comment: @bolov then he at least should mention for which compiler, should he not?

Comment: he wants a way to automatically catch these kinds of errors, similar of how accessing null will throw a NullPointerException in java

Comment: The compiler is MSVC 10.0 and gcc 4.9. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @bolov the he should use java

Comment: @Davidius: Added the test for nullness in the answer - simply use that before attempting to dereference.

Comment: I know that. I was looking for possibility to move the segmentation fault (or an exception) into a different location so the it is clear who dereferenced the nullpointer. That would ease the process of finding where the nullpointer was used.

Comment: @Davidius: No you can't do that. There is no defined behaviour when dereferencing a nullptr. Your only option is to test it as I state above and throw an exception &c. yourself.

Comment: @Davidius when you dereferencing a pointer in C++ you should always think "can this pointer be a nullptr?" and always check (at least by assert) unless you completely sure it is not possible.

Comment: @Slava I'm not the one dereferencing, I'm the one who gets the dereferenced reference.

Answer (score 0):

> To ease the finding of the error I want the dereferencing to fail on nullpointers so that the segmentation fault is caused in the above code. Is it possible to achieve this and how?

There is no actual dereferencing happens in code snippet you mentioned - I mean no memory access necessary when you define a reference. But things are even worse - even when you start to use that reference compiler is not obligated by C++ standard to check for `nullptr`, so there is no portable way to check it automatically. Only portable way - provide code that validates it manually:

```
int* a = 0;
assert( a );
int& b = *a;
```

this way you will validate correctness in debug mode and would not have this code in release. Or you can put code that always checks it. Point is - it is your responsibility to decide if you are willing to pay that price of validating pointers. Some of compilers though have options to enable `nullptr` detection, you should rely on compiler documentation for that. But that way is not portable at all. And even when you use that flag there is no guaratntee that such validation would happen when you declare a reference (especially when optimization enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Bathsheba's answer:

You could put that code inside a try-catch statement and raise an exception when the pointer is a nullptr and then do something. For example

```
enum PointerException {
     NullReference = 1
};
```

And then something like:

```
try {
    if(!ptr) {
       //Your pointer ain't null, do something.
    } else {
       //Your pointer is null, raise an exception.
       throw PointerException::NullReference;
    }
} catch(PointerException exception) {
   //Do something with your exception
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer throwing something like `struct NullReference{};` and throwing that, so you can have less ambiguity at catch sites.